# Can a UWP app be given access to the download folder on install?

Tags: uwp

Our UWP app needs access to delete any PDF from the user's downloads folder, so I've added a file picker to our Settings page to add the folder to StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList. (I don't want to access a sub folder in Downloads - it has to be the actual Downloads folder.)

The customer does not want to have to set this folder for all 1000 devices, so has asked if this permission could be given on install. For example, a message could pop up saying "Allow app to access the downloads folder?"

I think the only way the app can get permission to use the dowload folder is via a Folder Picker. This link seems to confirm it:
[File access permissions - Windows UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: If the user can allow this permission on every install.. can they not accept the pop up for the permission on the first launch of the application ?

Comment: You want to give Download folder access permission and your app installed. right?

Comment: Yes @NicoZhu-MSFT I want to give the Download folder access permission as the app is installed.

Comment: This is hard to achieve, I suggest update your app and add File access permission.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT How do I do that in a Windows UWP app? I can see permission for the Music or Videos library but not the Downloads folder.

Comment: Please check [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)capability.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've added the capability in the packages manifest, but it is underlined. Error says "The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities'" When I try to call StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(), I get "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189207/discussion-between-gail-foad-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: You also need open file access permission in the setting -> privacy -> file system.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I managed to get it working, but I find it doesn't work every time. Sometimes, even though I've set File System Privacy for my app, it doesn't let access the file system. I'm going to go back to the file picker option, but thank you for your help.